# Body background color not transitioning as other divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I am playing with front-end recently at FreeCodeCamp.
When doing a quote distributor, I managed to make elements background-color transition, but not the body, even if I applied the same transitions.

The Pen from Codepen is here : https://codepen.io/louis__/full/dXpwLx/

The html :

```
<body class="color-front">
  <div class="container-fluid color-back">
    <div class="jumbotron"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
          <div class="quote color-front"><a class="fa fa-quote-left color-front"></a> <span id="quote">Ceci est ma citation de départ, elle est peut-être toujours un peu courte !</span> <a class="fa fa-quote-right color-front"></a></div>
          <p class="text-right quote color-front">- <b><span id="author">Me</span></b></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
              <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter low social color-back"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="newquote" class="low change text-center color-back">New Quote</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="container-fluid color-back">
    <div class="jumbotron"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Parts of interest from 
- the css :

```
.color-back {
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
.color-front {
  -webkit-transition: color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: color 1000ms linear;
  transition: color 1000ms linear;
  color: blue;
  font-color: blue !important;
}

body {
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

and the JQuery :

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("#newquote").on("click", function() 
  {
    $("body").css("background-color", quotes[i].color);
    $("#quote").html(quotes[i].quote);
    $("#author").html(quotes[i].author);
    $(".color-back").css("background-color", quotes[i].color);
    $(".color-front").css("color", quotes[i].color);
    i = (i + 1)%quotes.length;
  });
});
```

As in the Pen, we first see the container-fluids and jumbotrons that are correctly transitioning, you have to drag the window up to see below, the body background not transitioning.

[image: start of the transition]

[image: middle of the transition]

[image: transition ended]

Any help will be appreciated, I am new to front-end development, and I still do not fully understand the inner logic of it.

Comment: body with class `color-front` have no `background-color`, applying a default background-color will make a difference.

Comment: It does, but strangely enough, the body still doesn't transition, and then updates its background-color with the previous color, not the current one. ie when divs are transitioning from color n-1 to color n, body updates to color n-1...

Comment: What type of transition you expecting from your body ? right now its fading transition working.

Comment: it's the container-fluids and the jumbotrons that are transitioning. If you drag the window up, you can see the body background not transitioning.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple CSS `transition`, you make a ruleset of 2 states (more if you use `keyframes`). The state that you begin with should have transitions, transforms, animation, etc. The end state should have at least the style that is expected (ex. from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* First State */

body {
  background: rgba(128, 64, 128, .8);
  transition: all 1s linear;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* First State */

.anim:before {
  position: relative;
  content: 'transition';
  color: rgba(255, 255, 0 .2);
  background: rgba(24, 64, 16, .2);
  opacity: .6;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
/* Last State */

.anim:hover:before {
  content: 'transition';
  color: rgba(255, 27, 128, 1);
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(128, 64, 0, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size: 32px;
}
/* Last State */

.anim:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 256, .4);
}
.static {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fc2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
</head>

<body class="anim">
  <div class="static">Hover
    <br/>Here</div>
</body>

</html>
```